# print statement from an import class works once the TTK windows is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I developed this code to use it as a calendar, and at the end, it return the date on a specific format.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt

class Calendar:

def __init__(self):
    self.b = 0

def calendar(self):

    calendar_window = Tk()
    calendar_window.title("Calendar")
    calendar_window.geometry("180x300")
    calendar_window.resizable(False,False)

    Label(calendar_window, text = "DATE") .place(x = 70, y =0)

    Label(calendar_window, text = "Month") .place(x = 30, y = 20)
    month = StringVar()
    month = ttk.Combobox(calendar_window, width = 5, textvariable = month , 
state = "readonly")
    month.place(x = 30, y = 40) 
    month['values'] = ['JAN' ,'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 
'AGU', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

    Label(calendar_window, text = "Year") .place(x = 110, y = 20)
    year = StringVar()
    year = ttk.Combobox(calendar_window, width = 5, textvariable = year , 
state = "readonly")
    year.place(x = 110, y = 40) 
    year["values"] = ["2015" ,"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", 
"2021", "2022"]
    year.current(0)

    day = StringVar()
    day_list = []

    def radiobutton_creation(event):
        days = Frame(calendar_window, width = 180, height = 150) 
        days.place(x = 3, y = 70)
        if month.current() != -1:
            d = QDate(int(year.get()), month.current() + 1, 1)
            x = [5,30,55,80,105,130,155]
            y = [5,35,65,95,125]
            i = 1
            for ver in y:
                for hor in x:
                    if i <= int(d.daysInMonth()): 
                        b = Radiobutton(days, text = 
str(i),variable=day,value= str(i), height = 1, width = 1,indicatoron=0) 
                        b.place(x = hor, y = ver)
                        day_list.append(b)
                        i = i + 1

    month.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', radiobutton_creation)
    year.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', radiobutton_creation)

    Label(calendar_window, text = "HH") .place(x = 55, y =220)
    hh = StringVar()
    hh = ttk.Combobox(calendar_window, width = 3, textvariable = hh,state = 
"readonly")
    hh.place(x = 55, y = 240) 
    hh["values"] = ["00","01" ,"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"]
    Label(calendar_window, text = "MM") .place(x = 100, y =220)
    mm = StringVar()
    mm = ttk.Combobox(calendar_window, width = 3, textvariable = mm,state = 
"readonly")
    mm.place(x = 100, y = 240) 
    mm["values"] = ["00","01" ,"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
 "09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16",
 "17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25"
,"26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34"
,"35","36","37","38","39","39","40","42","43"
,"44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52"
,"53","54","55","56","57","58","59"]
    Label(calendar_window, text = "Z") .place(x = 145, y =240)

    def select():
        if len(day.get()) < 2:
            self.b = 
('0'+day.get()+hh.get()+mm.get()+"Z"+month.get()+year.get())
            calendar_window.destroy()
        else:
            self.b = 
(day.get()+hh.get()+mm.get()+"Z"+month.get()+year.get())
            calendar_window.destroy()

    Button(calendar_window, text = "Select", command = select) .place(x = 
30, y = 270)
    Button(calendar_window, text = "Cancel", command = 
calendar_window.destroy) .place(x = 90, y = 270)


    calendar_window.update()


    calendar_window.mainloop()

    return returns()
```

It works fine, even if a create a new .py file and I code:

```
from calendar_class import Calendar
print(Calendar().calendar())
```

Nevertheless when I try to use this with a Label in Tkinter, it doesn`t work:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from calendar_class import Calendar

master = Tk()
master.title("ATO (Air Tasking Order)")
master.geometry('500x500')
def execute():
 date = StringVar()
 date.set(Calendar().calendar())
 Label(master, textvariable = date) .grid(row = 1, column = 1)
Button(master, text = 'Show Date', command = execute) .grid(row = 2, column 
= 2)
mainloop()
```

Or just trying to use print inside a ttk() window it works after the window is closed:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from calendar_class import Calendar


master = Tk()
master.title("ATO (Air Tasking Order)")
master.geometry('500x500')
print(Calendar().calendar())
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the call to `mainloop` in calendar class method. When you call `mainloop` function, your code gets stuck there waiting for user events on you GUI. It can only go to next line of code when `quit` is called on it, which in your case is called when you close the window.

I would suggest to use `calendar_window.update()` in your class method, which will draw your window but will not block your code there. Don't remove the `mainloop` call from your main function, otherwise the code will not wait for any user input and end execution instantly.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/5319738) for more details about working of mainloop.

UPDATE:

Sorry, I did not try to run your code last time. Assuming you are returning the selected date from `Calendar` class, these changes in `Calendar` class can solve your problem.

```
def select():
    if len(day.get()) < 2:
        self.b = ('0'+day.get()+hh.get()+mm.get()+"Z"+month.get()+year.get())
        calendar_window.quit()
    else:
        self.b = (day.get()+hh.get()+mm.get()+"Z"+month.get()+year.get())
        calendar_window.quit()

Button(calendar_window, text = "Select", command = select) .place(x = 30, y = 270)
Button(calendar_window, text = "Cancel", command = calendar_window.quit) .place(x = 90, y = 270)

calendar_window.mainloop()
calendar_window.destroy()

return self.b
```

So when you call the `quit` on button click, it will call `destroy` and then go to next call of `return`. And you can use your main function as showed in the question and it will work.

And why directly calling `destroy` on button click is not working (I guess) is related to use of two `Tk()` windows in same application(not suggested). So I would suggest to pass your `master` window as argument to `Calendar` class and then create `Toplevel` window instead of new `Tk()` window there. You can read more about `Toplevel` window [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

Hope this solves your problem finally.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem..:-)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I try using the update and still using the mainloop as you told me, but this is not working, at the end is the same. I am doing a deep research about the topic to understand it better, thanks

Comment: Please update the exact code you tried, and I can try that at my end.

Comment: I already update it, I am not even sure about where to locate the .update(). I put it at the end of the code, just before the mainloop(). I am not sure if it is right, but it is clearly not working

Comment: I already update it, I am not even sure about where to locate the .update(). I put it at the end of the code, just before the mainloop(). I am not sure if it is right, but it is clearly not working

Comment: I tried your code, In the Calendar class last call is `return returns()`, but I can't see the definition of function `returns` anywhere.

Comment: I am sorry In just checked your updated answer, using top level is the kwy to solve the problem, you are correct, thank you again